# Enable push state in Durandal

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, single-page-application, durandal

I created the single page application with asp.net (empty ASP.NET application)and Durandal.
I have to mention that I didn't use the MVC. Durandal works perfect when i use Hashtag. as soon as I enable the push state the routing is not working and i have 404 error.
so i decided to redirect all page to the index.html page but the problem is after I redirect all requests to index page(to prevent 404 error) the routing doesn't work(because after redirect, URL will be changed to index.html).
how can i fix this issue?

Just FYI:
for test purpose i created separate project and i used MVC application,everything works perfect after I add

```
   routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{*url}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
```

to Route.config. but i don't want to use MVC.

Comment: If you don't want to use MVC then why are you using it? Wouldn't creating an empty ASP.NET application be better for your purpose?

Comment: i didn't use MVC .exactly i created the empty ASP.NET application.

Comment: So why are you configuring routing?

Comment: if you read the explanation i mentioned that for more test i implemented in the MVC in the  separate project and push state works fine in the mvc.